# Publish related articles in the same journal or in different journals?

Tags: mathematics, online-publication

I have done a lot of research on curling numbers, which is a particular niche of combinatorics. There have only been two earlier publications on curling numbers, both in the Journal of Integer sequences. I am planning to publish my new results in three articles. They don't use results from each other. Is it better to publish them all in the Journal of Integer Sequences, or in different journals?

Comment: "Best" for what purpose?

Comment: For example: chances of having all articles accepted, reaching people with the material.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that JIS has a "one paper at a time" policy. If you don't have a need to rush all three papers into publication then you can submit the first and see what the response is.

Caveat: I make no judgement on the quality of the journal. Being free to all is an advantage in some ways.

But, for visibility, I'd guess that having several papers in the same journal is marginally better, though it has little effect for free, online, journals. The more important question, however, is "What is the most appropriate journal for this work?". You can judge that from the papers they have already published.

Comment: Could you explain why having several papers in the same journal is marginally better for visibility?

Comment: Simply because if a person finds one they can easily find the others. They know where to go without searching. Marginal, though, as I said.